# Overloaded 'operator++' must be a unary or binary operator (has 3 parameters)

Tags: c++, xcode, operator-overloading, post-increment, pre-increment

I have a header file and a .cpp file. I am trying to implement a prefix and postfix operator overload but I keep getting this error when setting up the overload.

fraction.h

```
#ifndef FRACTION_H
#define FRACTION_H

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Fraction 
{
   public:
      Fraction();
      Fraction(int, int);
      int getTop() {return m_top;}
      int getBottom() {return m_bottom;}
      void set(int t, int b) {m_top=t; m_bottom=b; reduce();
      }

   protected:
   private:
      void reduce();
      int gcf(int, int);

      int m_top;
      int m_bottom;
};

Fraction& operator ++ (Fraction);
Fraction operator++(Fraction, int);

#endif
```

Main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
#include "fraction.h"

int main {
   cout << "The fraction is" << f;
   cout << "The output of ++f is " << (++f) << endl;
   cout << "The fraction is" << f;
   cout << "The output of f++ is " << (f++) << endl;
   cout << "The fraction is" << f;

   return 0;
}

Fraction& Fraction::operator ++ (Fraction){
   // Increment prefix
   m_top += m_bottom;
   return *this;
}

Fraction Fraction::operator ++ (Fraction, int){
   //Increment postfix
}
```

These are the two errors I get:

```
 prefix error: "Parameter of overloaded post-increment operator must have type 'int' (not 'Fraction')"

postfix error: "Overloaded 'Operator++' must be a unary or binary operator (has 3 parameters)"
```

Is the prefix error actually an error with my ide? I know it must be 'int' for post-increment, but I am trying to do a pre-increment. I use xcode.

Comment: There are several issues in your code. Here are a few, fixing which might get you the answer. In `fraction.h` you declare a class named `fraction` but the increment operators are using a class named `Fraction`. In `fraction.h` you declare non-member versions of the two operators while in `Main.cpp` you are defining operators that are member functions of class `Fraction`. See [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_incdec) for details regarding inside class and outside class definitions of the operators.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You declared the operators outside the class as non-class functions

```
Fraction& operator ++ (Fraction);
Fraction operator++(Fraction, int);
```

however then you are trying to define them like class member functions

```
Fraction& Fraction::operator ++ (Fraction){
   // Increment prefix
   m_top += m_bottom;
   return *this;
}

Fraction Fraction::operator ++ (Fraction, int){
   //Increment postfix
}
```

Either declare them as class member functions the following way

```
class Fraction
{
public:
    Fraction & operator ++();
    Fraction operator ++( int );
    //...
```

And in this case the definition for example of the preincrement operator can look like

```
Fraction & Fraction::operator ++(){
   // Increment prefix
   m_top += m_bottom;
   return *this;
}
```

Or declare them as non-class function that are friends of the class because they need to have access to private data members of the class

```
class Fraction
{
public:
    friend Fraction & operator ++( Fraction & );
    friend Fraction operator ++( Fraction &, int );
    //...
```

And in this case the definition for example of the preincrement operator can look like

```
Fraction & operator ++( Fraction &f ){
   // Increment prefix
   f.m_top += f.m_bottom;
   return f;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You declared the functions as free functions

```
Fraction& operator ++ (Fraction);
Fraction operator++(Fraction, int);
```

but you are defining them as member functions.

```
Fraction& Fraction::operator ++ (Fraction){ ... }
Fraction& Fraction::operator ++ (Fraction, int){ ... }
```

Since member functions have an implicit `this` parameter, your member functions have three parameters (`this`, `Fraction`, and `int`).

Decide whether you want the functions to be free or member. If you want them to be free, then define them as free rather than member. If you want them to be member, then declare them as member and adjust the declarations as noted by @crayzeewulf above.

Answer (score 0):

A member function has an implicit *this pointer which always points to the class object the member function is working on. The parameter we had to list explicitly in the friend function version (which doesn’t have a *this pointer) becomes the implicit *this parameter in the member function version.

Try making it a non member function.Then you can pass the parameter
Otherwise remove the parameter.

Answer (score -2):

```
    int main() {
    Fraction f;
    cout << "The fraction is" << f;
    cout << "The output of ++f is " << (++f) << endl;
    cout << "The fraction is" << f;
    cout << "The output of f++ is " << (f++) << endl;
    cout << "The fraction is" << f;


    return 0;
    }

    Fraction& Fraction::operator++ ()
    {
        // Increment prefix
        m_top += 1;
        return *this;
    }

    const Fraction Fraction::operator++ (int)
    {
        //Increment postfix
        Fraction temp = *this;
        ++(*this);
        return temp;
    }

    ostream& operator<<(ostream &os, const Fraction& f)
    {
        os << f.m_top << endl;
        return os;
    }

    Fraction::Fraction(const Fraction& f)
    {
        m_top = f.m_top;
        m_bottom = f.m_bottom;
    }

    Fraction::Fraction(int t, int b) :m_top(t), m_bottom(b){}
    Fraction::Fraction() : m_top(1), m_bottom(1){}


     class Fraction
    {
    public:
        Fraction();
        Fraction(int, int);
        Fraction(const Fraction& f);
        int getTop() { return m_top; }
        int getBottom() { return m_bottom; }
        void set(int t, int b) {
            m_top = t; m_bottom = b; reduce();
        }
        Fraction& operator ++ ();
        const Fraction operator++(int);

        friend ostream& operator<<(ostream &os,const Fraction& f);

        protected:
        private:
        void reduce();
        int gcf(int, int);

        int m_top;
        int m_bottom;
        };
        #endif
```